# Cannot install Nvidia driver for Quadro 1700 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I tried going into TTY mode. And stopping lightdm service. And running the driver downloaded from Nvidia website. And it gives the error "The distribution provided preinstall script failed!"

Comment: Could you provide more information? For example, your OS and installation method?

Comment: the file is a **.run** file and i'm **sh**-ing it in **TTY** as root and with **chmod +x** -ing the driver file.

Comment: You don't need to do that. You can and *should* install the drivers directly from the Ubuntu repositories and that can be easily done at Additional Drivers. Sometimes you may need to add an additional software source to obtain newer versions but that is NOT applicable to a Quadro FX1700 (legacy hardware) that runs with 340 version and that version only.

Comment: @MichalBay That is the most common method; but wasn't necessary for me. Then again, I had a different combination (Ubuntu 14.04 with Quadro P5000)